# three.js apply texture to a given plane

Tags: three.js, textures, texture-mapping

I want to apply a texture on a given plane. I can display a texture on a PlaneGeometry but I want to do it on a plane for which I precise the corners coordinates.

My working code to apply a texture (video or image) on a PlaneGeometry :

```
var materialVideo, videoGeometry, videoMesh;
var video, videoTexture, videoImage, videoImageContext;
var videoPlan,videoPlanMesh;        

function testVideo()
{
    video = document.createElement('video');
    video.loop=true;
    video.width    = 480;
    video.height   = 204;
    video.autoplay = true;
    video.src = "./video.mp4";
    video.load(); 

    videoImage = document.createElement('canvas');
    videoImage.width = 480;
    videoImage.height = 204;

    videoImageContext = videoImage.getContext('2d');
    videoImageContext.fillStyle = 'rgb( 200,0,0 )';
    videoImageContext.fillRect( 0, 0, videoImage.width, videoImage.height);

    videoTexture = new THREE.Texture( videoImage );
    videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

    materialVideo = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: videoTexture, overdraw: true, side:THREE.DoubleSide });

    //if an image, not a video
    //var image = new Image();
    //image.src="./texture.jpg";
    //materialVideo.map.image = image;

    /************************************/
    //display on a PlaneGeometry   
    videoGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(160,120,4,4);

    videoMesh = new THREE.Mesh(videoGeometry, materialVideo);
    videoMesh.position.x= 80;
    videoMesh.position.y= 0;
    videoMesh.position.z= -50;
    videoMesh.rotation.y=0;

    scene.add( videoMesh );
    /************************************/
}
```

To display on a plane with given corners, I replace the previous block "display on a PlaneGeometry" by this one :

```
videoPlan = new THREE.Geometry();
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,50,-50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,50,50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,-50,50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,-50,-50));

videoPlan.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2));
videoPlan.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 3));

videoPlanMesh = new THREE.Mesh(videoPlan, materialVideo);
scene.add( videoPlanMesh );
```

but nothing appears and I get the error :

[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

What is my mystake?

**EDIT for answer** :
Indeed, UV coordinates are missing, so finally, I have the following working code :

```
videoPlan = new THREE.Geometry();
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,50,-50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,50,50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,-50,50));
videoPlan.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(100,-50,-50));

videoPlan.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2));
videoPlan.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 2, 3));

videoPlan.faceVertexUvs[0][0]=[new THREE.UV(0, 1),new THREE.UV(1, 1),new THREE.UV(1, 0)];
videoPlan.faceVertexUvs[0][1]=[new THREE.UV(0, 1),new THREE.UV(1, 0),new THREE.UV(0, 0)];

videoPlanMesh = new THREE.Mesh(videoPlan, materialVideo);
scene.add( videoPlanMesh );
```

Comment: you need to add uv coordinates. take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238944/how-do-i-add-a-texture-to-a-triangle-in-three-js

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I edited my post to add the correct code.